# Why the table's inside element's width is not fixed even it's given a fixed number?

Tags: html, css

I have a DOM structure like this:

`div#holder > table > tbody > tr > td`

I have specified the `td` to be a fixed widht of `15px`. But when I resize the `#holder`'s width, the `td`'s width changed.

I would like to know:

1. Why the given number is not ruling?
2. How can I make the `td`'s width fixed?

Thanks,

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var w = 300*Math.random();
  $('#holder').css('width', w + 'px');
},500)
```

```css
td {
width:15px;
height:50px;
background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var w = 300*Math.random();
  $('#holder').css('width', w + 'px');
},500)
```

Well this is happening because of the Javascript that you have written.
The td is adapting to the parent table's width (#holder)in this case, and the static width of 15px is changing after every 0.5 seconds.
If you use max-width:15px instead of width:15px for td.Then only the table width will change as per the your code and your td's will remain 15px fixed and your issue will be resolved.

```
td{
max-width:15px;
height:50px;
background:#f00;
}
#holder{
border:2px solid black;
}
```

Then td will not grow or shrink with respect to its parent.
As can be seen below.

[image: I just increased the timeInterval to 5 seconds and took this snap shot.As you can see now only the table width is changing not the td's width]

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to be? All you did was copy the JS part of the snippet provided.

Comment: It's all fine now.That I actually copied to work on my editor and fix the Questioners Issue locally.But It was mistakenly added as answer without me observing.Now all is fine and perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min-width` and `max-width` to set an *exact* width of an element. You can see the result here.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var w = 300*Math.random();
  $('#holder').css('width', w + 'px');
},500)
```

```css
td {
  min-width: 15px;
  max-width: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```